# Pandas: New text column depending on another text column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column type object which includes a text. I would like to create a New Column in the same df with a text depending on the text of this first column. This would be an example: a column with the city and a new column that would specify the country:

```
      City           New Column
0   New York         USA    
1      Paris         France
2      Lyon          France
3   Los Angeles      USA
4     Madrid         Spain
5   Washington       USA
6   Barcelona        Spain
```

I would do it with `df.loc[]` if the values would be int or float but with type object I receive a new column NaN. Any suggestion how to do it with less code possible in python? Thanks!

Comment: could you be more precise on where are the values you want to put in "new column" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a `mapping dict`. Then you can use `map`

```
map_dict = {
    'USA': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Washington'],
    'France': ['Paris', 'Lyon'],
    'Spain': ['Madrid', 'Barcelona']
}
df['New Column'] = df.City.map({x: i for i, j in map_dict.items() for x in j})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try np.select:

[Same thing using np.select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHpI8.png)